# TypeScript error when createBrowserHistory's push method may not exist

Tags: typescript

If I check for the history object then my code has no errors:

```
   const handleClick = () => {
     if (history) {
       history.push('/');
     }
   };
```

I thought that this would be the same, but it produces a TypeScript error:

```
  const handleClick = () => {
    // if (history) {
    history?.push('/');
    // }
  };
```

> error TS2339: Property 'push' does not exist on type '"" | History<{} | null | undefined>'.
> Property 'push' does not exist on type '""'.

> 27     history?.push('/');

Are they not in fact the same thing?

The history I'm importing is this:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default process.env.BROWSER && createBrowserHistory();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an error because the `?` operator is actually not going to prevent you from running the function, which may fail if `history` is not set this is why TypeScript throws an error. When this code compiles it may still fail, and TypeScript is trying to prevent that failure.

the `?` operator will only prevent you from "trying to access a property on a null or undefined" but wont prevent the a function invocation.

this like you mentioned

```js
 const handleClick = () => {
     if (history) {
       history.push('/');
     }
   };
```

or this

```js
 const handleClick = () => {
     history && history.push('/')
  };
```

Are correct ways to go about this